# GetFiles method is not working

Tags: c#, pdf

I have this code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string filepath = @"d:";

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);


        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles(" *.pdf"))
        {
            SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new PdfFocus();

            f.OpenPdf(@"d:" + file.Name);

            if (f.PageCount > 0)
                f.ToExcel(@"d:" + file.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

When I debug this code, I see that **d.GetFiles("*.pdf")** is not working as expected. Can you tell me why is that? I have pdf files in D:// folder but `d.GetFiles()` returns empty. Can you tell me the error, Thanks.

Comment: If you remove the space before the " *.pdf" probably it will work better. And if you use the more appropriate Path.Combine instead of building paths by your own then it will work even better

Comment: Well, do you have many files that has a filename that starts with a space?

Comment: instead of `@"d:" + file.Name` use `file.FullName`.  But I doubt you want to pass the same file name to `ToExcel`.  I would assume you actually want something like `f.ToExcel(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName) + ".xlsx");`

Comment: your folder path is not correct.  `string filepath = @"d:\";`. Inculde '\'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d.GetFiles(" *.xlsx") to d.GetFiles("*.xlsx")
```

space-character problem

Comment: `f.OpenPdf(@"d:" + file.Name); ` Is this a smart thing to do? Or how can I make this work, it's still not working..

Comment: @jason try `f.OpenPdf(file.FullName);` instead.

Comment: f.OpenPdf(@"d:\" + file.Name); or f.OpenPdf(file.FullName);  try it @jason

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the Space from `d.GetFiles(" *.pdf")`

It should be:

```
d.GetFiles("*.pdf")
```